# Common Trend Assumption in Difference-in-differences

Tags: regression, econometrics, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect, matching

I'm running a DiD analysis on whether the introduction of a spinoff NFT (non-fungible token) collection affects the prices of the parent NFT collection. First thing that I did is to visually test whether the paraller trend assumption holds or not.

Here's the plot (CryptoPunks (control group), BAYC (treatment group).

[image: CTA Plot]

At first glance it seems that the paraller trend assumption holds, however, to be on the safe side I did also a placebo test where I:

1. Droped all the outcomes for observations after the introduction of a spinoff NFT collection (treatment).
2. Inserted a phantom treatment event in the middle of the remaining data and created a dummy variable after_change (0 - before, 1 - after the phantom treatment).
3. Ran my diff-in-diff model and checked the interaction coefficient.

The DiD specification I used:

> log(Sold_Price)i = β0 + β1After_Shockt + β2BAYC_NFTi + β3After_Shockt × BAYC_NFTi + εit

BAYC = dummy variable (0 - control group, 1 - treatment group)

This is the code that I used:

```
Model1 = lm(log_total_price_usd ~ after_change + BAYC + after_change * BAYC, data = NFTs)
tidy(Model1)
```

These are the results that I got:

[image: Placebo Test DiD]

I find it super weird that the plot indicates paraller trends, however I get statistical significance in the placebo test which according to the plot should not be there.

Finally, these are the normal results, with the real treatment event that I got using the same code.

[image: Normal DiD]

Could someone please explain whether I'm doing something wrong here, is this normal to get such results and if not what could I do about it?

Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. Just to be clear, is that a plot showing your phantom event date, or is that the outcome variation for both groups before and after the “actual” treatment?

Comment: My appologies for not clarifying that, but the plot represents the outcome variation for both groups before and after the "actual" treatment.

Comment: If I may ask, what was the fake event date? Also, what’s your sample size? There might not be anything wrong here.

Comment: So the research period of the "actual" analysis is from July 16, 2021 to October 10, 2021 (the "actual" treatment took place on August 28, 2021, this date was excluded) and it comprises of 86 days. The sample size for the "actual" analysis is 9058 (Treatment group - N 5168, Control group - N 3890).

The research period for the "phantom" analysis is from July 16, 2021 to August 27, 2021 (the "phantom" treatment date is August 6, 2021, to split the before/after evenly i.e., 21 days before/after). The number of obesrvations for "phantom" analysis is 6695.